# In Spark AR, how to anchor an object to an image tracker first, then make it stay fixed onscreen even if tracker isn't visible?

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

How do I set up an object in Spark AR to initially appear on the screen based on an image tracker, but then stay in place even after the image tracker is no longer visible? I want the object to be positioned using the image tracker as a reference point, but I don't want the image tracker to be visible once the object has appeared.

I attempted to anchor an object to an image tracker in Spark AR by setting up the object's position relative to the tracker. I expected the object to appear on the screen when the image tracker was in view, and then stay fixed in that position even when the tracker was out of view. However, once the image tracker was no longer visible, the object also disappeared from the screen. My goal was to have the object remain in the fixed position on the screen, using the image tracker's initial position as a reference, even when the tracker was not visible.